# Linear programming: constraints that depend on sign

Tags: probability-distributions, linear-programming

**Edit:** *following a comment, more detail and context, and removed lengthy confusing remains of previous edits*

I basically want to check whether there is a sequence $y_1,\dots, y_n \in (-\infty,0]$ that satisfies the following, where $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are known and correspond to a probability distribution: $p_i\in[0,1]$, $\sum_i p_i = 1$; and $\alpha$ is a (fixed) small constant.
$$\begin{align}
& y_i \leq 0 \\
& y_{i+1} \geq y_{i} \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert e^{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} y_j} - e^{\sum_{j=1}^{i} y_j} - p_i \rvert \leq \alpha
\end{align}
$$
**The goal** find $y_i$'s that can be used to get a structured probability distribution whose $\ell_1$ distance to $p$ is no more than $C\cdot\alpha$ for some constant $C$, *if* we are promised there exists one at distance $\leq \alpha$ (I have some slack regarding $C$, even something like 10 or 1000 would be fine).

That is, this linear program is trying to enforce that the probability distribution obtained (after renormalization) by setting $q_i \stackrel{\rm def}{=} (1-e^{y_i})e^{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} y_j}$ have some particular structure (be a "monotone hazard rate" distribution (MHR)). (The fact that the $q_i$'s before renormalization should almost sum to one is not an issue, and approximately taken care of by the $\ell_1$ distance between $q$ and $p$). So the problem is really the last constraint.

Let me know if the above is remotely clear...

Comment: Instead of asking a somewhat vague question about a particular approach to handling the unspecified nonlinearities in your problem, I think you should simply be sharing more specifics about your nonlinearities and seeking advice on how to handle the *actual* constraint.

Comment: And if I understand what you're trying to do (but I'm not sure I do) the solution will require something beyond linear programming. So again, there's another vote for being more specific and direct about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelGrant See above -- I did my best to add background and details.

Comment: @Clement C. I agree with Michael Grant, you should just open a new discussion with the non linear constrained optimization problem explained clearly, (in 5 lines maximum), then we will see if it is related to linear programming, because for now nobody understood your $X_i$'s and $\alpha_i$'s etc.

Comment: @reuns did you have a look at the edit (second part of the question)?

Comment: @Clement C. no, because I didn't understand the first part after 30 seconds. this is how posts are read in math forums. switch first and second part, or even delete first part !! good advice don't worry.

Comment: @reuns: OK -- I trimmed a lot :)

Comment: and it's quadratic constrains :
$-\alpha < p_i - Z_{i-1} (Y_i-1)  < \alpha$ where $Z_i = Z_{i-1} Y_i$ and $1 \ge Y_i  > Y_{i-1} > 0$.

you can add extra variables to be minimized : 

$-\psi_i< p_i - Z_{i-1} (Y_i-1)  < \psi_i$, $0 \le \psi_i < \alpha$, $-\phi_i < Z_i - Z_{i-1} Y_i < \phi_i$, $\phi_i > 0$, $\min \sum  \psi_i + \beta \sum \phi_i$

which you can solve if your problem has a finite number of variables. then, you would like to  find a criterion for feasibility in the non-finite case ?

Comment: @reuns I only have a finite number of variables (it's a discrete probability distribution) -- my issue is that I want to guarantee a polynomial (in $n$ and $1/\alpha$) running time, which I don't know how to ensure with quadratic constraints.